# Same value written to the array when a text file read

Tags: c

I tried to read a text file into an array using following code, but each and every value of the array gets the final line read from the text file.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char line[255];
    char *kernal[3];

    FILE *fpointer_1 = fopen("sample.txt", "r");

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        fgets(line, 255, fpointer_1);

        kernal[i] = line;
    };

    fclose(fpointer_1);

    printf("1st value : %s\n", kernal[0]);
    printf("2nd value : %s\n", kernal[1]);
    printf("3rd value : %s\n", kernal[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why that happens and how to solve the issue ?

Comment: Please don't post images of code; post the code as plain text.  All else apart, we can't simply copy and test your code when it's an image (it's also unreadable on phones).

Comment: Since you read each line into the variable `line`, how do you expect it to hold three different values at the same time?

Comment: You are overwriting `line` on each iteration, switch to `char line[3][255];` and `fgets(line[i], ...`

Comment: each `kernal[i]` is a pointer. each `kernal[i]` points to the first element of the array `line`. You need to arrange some memory and copy data from `line` there (and make `kernal` pointers point there).

Comment: maybe `char kernal[3][255];` and `strcpy(kernal[i], line);`

Comment: OT: **always** check if `fopen` fails, the file you're trying to open might not exist. Yes, this happens more often than you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the `kernal[i] = line` line. **You always** point to the same line. You need to allocate it a memory, then use `strcpy` to copy the contents from the `line` array to the new allocated memory.

```c
kernal[i] = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
strcpy(kernal[i], line];
```